# Hatcher's representation of coverings spaces as permutations

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

So, I was going through Hatcher's argument on how covering spaces can be classified by their association with permutation groups, and was able to understand everything until here:
[image]

1) How exactly is it evident that $L_{\gamma}(h(\tilde{x_{0}})) = h(L_{\gamma}(\tilde{x_{0}}))?$ Is it something to do with the fact that both $L_{\gamma}$ and $h$ are bijections?

2)Why is the relationship above "what we would naturally call an isomorphism on actions"?

3)How does the isomorphism $h:F_{1} \rightarrow F_{2}$ induce an isomorphism $h:\tilde{X_{1}} \rightarrow \tilde{X_{2}}$?

4) Finally, why is the identification in the last paragraph of conjugacy groups the relation we use? How did Hatcher reach this conclusion from the preceeding paragraph?

Comment: For (1) note that $L_\gamma$ on the left and $L_\gamma$ on the right side are **two different maps**. One is associated to $p_1$ covering and the other to $p_2$ (being isomorphic to $p_1$ via $h$). There's no simpler way to explain the relationship then going through definitions. Both being bijections **doesn't** matter.

Comment: For (2) what Hatcher says is simply that $\pi_1(X)$ acts on both $F_1$ and $F_2$ and the bijectios $F_1\to F_2$ preserves that action. More generally for a given group $G$ a bijection that preserves $G$-action is known as a $G$-isomorphism *or* an isomorphism of $G$-action.

Comment: [these notes](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~jmb/note/gsetcov.pdf) might be helpful.